# Use Mathematica to split a sequence according to other two sequences

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, sequence

I want to use Mathematica to solve the following problem:

For example I have a sequence 101. I want to compare it with $1101$ and $0101$. The comparison has the following procedure:

1. Check the first term of $101$ is $1$ or $0$. If it is $1$, compare $101$ to $1101$, term by term; If it is $0$, compare $101$ to $0101$. Stop the process before the first term they are different, or all the terms of $101$ have been compared without stopping the process, and report all the terms that have been compared.

*In our case, the first term of $101$ is $1$, so we compare it with $1101$. Then, $101$ and $1101$ only has one term in common, the first term $1$. So the program should report $1$, and go to next step.*

2. Recording the remaining sequence of $101$.

*In our case, as only $1$ is reported, the remaining sequence is $01$.*

3. Restart the process. Check the first term of $01$ is $0$ or $1$. If it $0$, compare $01$ with $0101$, if it is $1$, compare $01$ with $1101$. Stop the process before the first term they are different, or the sequence of $01$ has been run out. Report all the timers that have been compared.

*In our case, the first term of $01$ is $0$, so we compare $01$ with $0101$. Then the first two terms agree, and then $01$ ran out. The program should report $01$, and then stop.

4. Repeating the process again and again until there is no remaining sequence.

I tried to use the commend "If" to write this but it did not work, since I did not know how to let Mathematica to "remember" what has been compared.

Then, I tried to use commend "Order" and "Sort", but it seems that I need to program a comparison function.

Is there anyway for me to achieve this using Mathematica? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** We can use `Split` to get the desired result in a single step:

```
ClearAll[sPlit]
sPlit[s0_, s1_][s_] := Module[{ref, x = Characters @ s}, 
  ref["0"] = Characters @ s0; 
  ref["1"] = Characters @ s1; 
  Module[{i = 0, rf = ref[x[[1]]]}, 
   StringJoin /@ Split[x, Or[{##} == rf[[{i++, i}]], i = 1; rf = ref[#2]] &]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
sPlit["0101", "1101"]["101"]
```

> ```
>  {"1", "01"}
> ```

```
sPlit["010111010", "110111010"]["10111010"]
```

> ```
>  {"1", "01", "1101", "0"}
> ```

```
sPlit[s0, s1][s] (* s, s0, s1 from the original answer below *)
```

> ```
>  {"0", "1", "1", "101", "001", "0", "101", "0", "1"}
> ```

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[lW, tD, steP, fP]

lW[l0_, l1_][x_] := LengthWhile[Range @ Length @ x, 
   x[[#]] == l0[[#]] || x[[#]] == l1[[#]] &]

tD[l0_, l1_][x_] := TakeDrop[x, lW[l0, l1][x]]

steP[l0_, l1_][{a___, b_List /; Length[b] > 0}] := {a, ## & @@ tD[l0, l1][b]}

steP[l0_, l1_][a : {___, {}}] := a

fP[s0_String, s1_String][s_String] := Module[{c = Characters /@ {s0, s1, s}}, 
  StringJoin /@ Most[FixedPoint[steP[c[[1]], c[[2]]], {c[[3]]}]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
fP["0101", "1101"]["101"]
```

> ```
>  {"1", "01"}
> ```

```
fP["010111010", "110111010"]["10111010"]
```

> ```
> {"1", "01", "1101", "0"}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[123]
s = RandomChoice[{"0", "1"}, 15];

{s, s0, s1} = StringJoin /@ {s, Prepend["0"]@s, Prepend["1"]@s}
```

> ```
> {"011101001010101", "0011101001010101", "1011101001010101"}
> ```

```
fP[s0, s1][s]
```

> ```
> {"0", "1", "1", "101", "001", "0", "101", "0", "1"}
> ```

Comment: OMG. Nice answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

> Such a Reading comprehension :)

Split the string:

```
a = StringSplit["101", ""]
b = StringSplit["1101", ""]
```

Get the large position by using NestWhile:

```
maxPos = NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, a[[#]] == b[[#]] &] - 1
```

> 1

```
a[[1 ;; maxPos]]
```

> {"1"}

The remaining items:

```
Take[a, Length@a - maxPos]
```

> {"1", "0"}

Then `Get the large position by using NestWhile:`, repeat it.

I'll leave the left to you :)

Comment: Thank you so much! And thank you for reading my long post :)) Brilliant code